# ASP.NET web api 2 how to reset token authentication when password is reset/change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

When the user changes their password, they get Logged Out from the app. However, if they are logged into another app at the same time they remain logged in on the other app.

I want to log out the user from all apps they are logged into when they change their password.

In browser we check the user cookie by this code

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
}
```

Is there are same code to web api?

Answer (score 0):

i think this link will help you ,

> [How to invalidate OAuth token when password is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776322/how-to-invalidate-oauth-token-when-password-is-changed)